# oracle PL/SQL update with byte array

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql

I have a byte array that i am trying to stuff into an existing record.
I need help with finishing the script.
Im not sure how to accept the byte array in the script.

I havent compiled the script yet in the database. Just want to make sure the script is working right first.

Here is  what the record looks like in the oracle db where i am trying to add a byte array into the column **LOGO** the table name is account

[image]

Here is the method that will call the pl/sql script. Im not 100% sure if its right.

```
public void saveLogo(final int accountID, final byte[] data){
    (new Call() {
        protected void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            CallableStatement statement = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            try {

                statement = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call updateCompanyLogo(?,?) }");
                statement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
                statement.setBytes(1, data);
                statement.setInt(2,accountID);
                statement.execute();
            } finally {
                stmt.close();
                connection.close();
            }

        }
    }).execute();
}
```

Here is my attempt at the pl/sql script that will stuff the byte array into the record.

```
create or replace function updateCompanyLogo (
l_accountID in number,
byte array(BLOB))

is

begin

update account
set logo = byte
where id = l_accountID;


end;

/
```

How do i add that byte array as a parameter in the pl/sql and set it?
Thanks in advance as i am stuck

Comment: Do you need to return a value from the PL/SQL script back into the Java code to do something with it? If not, remove all the "return" logic from the script (which appears to be incorrect anyway) and just "{CALL updateCompanyLogo(?,?)}" with two input parameters: the number and the byte array(BLOB).

Comment: I updated the pl/sql can you see if it looks correct?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the LOGO column is of type BLOB, the PL/SQL script should look something like

```
create or replace function updateCompanyLogo (
l_accountID in number,
p_Array in BLOB)

as

begin

update account
set logo = p_Array
where id = l_accountID;


end;

/
```

And the subsequent Java logic for the call should be like:

```
stmt = connection.prepareCall("{CALL updateCompanyLogo(?,?)}");
stmt.setInt(1,accountID);
stmt.setBytes(2, accountID);
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: column is a type BLOB

Comment: @piddler then this should get you down the road to where you need to be

Comment: i will get back to you. Im trying it out.

Comment: the is before begin is expecting a return. I tried removing the is and begin was in red.

Comment: @piddler see edit. I changed the `is` to `as`  ---- second edit: I just noticed this is a function and not a procedure. Functions require a return. You can return 0 and it will just get thrown away by the Java code.

Comment: it doesnt like the as its in red

Comment: i added a return and its happy now with the is instead